# Is it possible to use dynamic controller name in routing in CodeIgniter 4?

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I want to use route localization like said here https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/outgoing/localization.html#in-routes

So I need to add route rule like:
`$routes->get('{locale}/books', 'App\Books::index');`

But I want to make this rule for all controllers - not to specify rules for all controllers. So I added the rule:
`$routes->add('{locale}/(:segment)(:any)', '$1::$2');`

I have controller `Login` with method `index()`. When I go to `mydomain.com/Login` method `index()` is loaded successfull. But when I go to `mydomain.com/en/Login` (as I expect to use my route) I got 404 Error with message - "Controller or its method is not found: \App\Controllers$1::index". But locale is defined and set correctly.

If I change my route to `$routes->add('{locale}/(:segment)(:any)', 'Login::$2');` then `mydomain.com/en/Login` is loaded successfull as I want. But in this way I have to set routes for every controller and I want to set **one** route to work with all controllers.

Is it possible to set route with setting of dynamic controller name?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it is possible directly, but here is a workaround:

`$routes->add('{locale}/(:segment)/(:any)', 'Rerouter::reroute/$1/$2');`

Then, your `Rerouter` classlooks like this:

```php
<?php namespace App\Controllers;

class Rerouter extends BaseController
{
    public function reroute($controllerName, ...$data)
    {
        $className = str_replace('-', '', ucwords($controllerName)); // This changes 'some-controller' into 'SomeController'.
        
        $controller = new $className();
        if (0 == count($data))
        {
            return $controller->index(); // replace with your default method
        }

        $method = array_shift($data);

        return $controller->{$method}(...$data);
    }
}
```

For example, `/en/user/show/john-doe` will call the controller `User::show('john-doe')`.

Comment: Yes, I also thought so - it would be nice to have one endpoint and all requests will go through it. But when I tryed to get instanse of class I've got error - Class 'User' not found. My `Rerouter` class and my `User` class are controllers in the same namespace `App\Controllers`.

Comment: When I set directly `$controller = new User();` then it work properly. Dynamically $className is not working for some reasons.

Comment: Other option: go to CodeIgniter forums and change your question into a feature request. I think it's something that should be included in the Framework!